# webRTC black remote stream on some network

Tags: google-chrome, video, webrtc

This is webRTC application on GWT/GAE working great except for some network configurations. In this case (when p2p video chat does not work) the network is the attMifi on one side and at&t (u-verse) on other side.
    We are using both STUN and TURN servers (turnservers.com). ICE candidates are exchanged just normal though in failure case iceConnectionStateChange stays stuck at "ICEConnectionStateChecking". 
    Below is offer/answer SDP from the browser client who made offer (and received answer). Both clients are on latest chrome. (Logs courtesy chrome://webrtc-internals)

```
type: offer, sdp: v=0
o=- 5390964131278613156 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS F9dcB5SiD7cSD2jrxdZruldnmAdiVaHK4dhL
m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 107 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:/Pt6xdNi5qhxh4Eu
a=ice-pwd:y69sYd+b5f6PNNVTqze+0e7g
a=ice-options:google-ice
a=fingerprint:sha-256 41:60:34:64:87:C3:79:92:49:9B:8A:2F:6E:A8:04:74:BF:63:2F:4A:D7:C0:60:1E:54:A3:0F:61:7A:CE:B4:89
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:QwIGi8fFaSR7fSNcEyqcNlEr014E3qfbyGzMvk9m
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:107 CN/48000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:2354337027 cname:zS0tMKeqqiAE+v9q
a=ssrc:2354337027 msid:F9dcB5SiD7cSD2jrxdZruldnmAdiVaHK4dhL F9dcB5SiD7cSD2jrxdZruldnmAdiVaHK4dhLa0
a=ssrc:2354337027 mslabel:F9dcB5SiD7cSD2jrxdZruldnmAdiVaHK4dhL
a=ssrc:2354337027 label:F9dcB5SiD7cSD2jrxdZruldnmAdiVaHK4dhLa0
m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:/Pt6xdNi5qhxh4Eu
a=ice-pwd:y69sYd+b5f6PNNVTqze+0e7g
a=ice-options:google-ice
a=fingerprint:sha-256 41:60:34:64:87:C3:79:92:49:9B:8A:2F:6E:A8:04:74:BF:63:2F:4A:D7:C0:60:1E:54:A3:0F:61:7A:CE:B4:89
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:QwIGi8fFaSR7fSNcEyqcNlEr014E3qfbyGzMvk9m
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc:1640957078 cname:zS0tMKeqqiAE+v9q
a=ssrc:1640957078 msid:F9dcB5SiD7cSD2jrxdZruldnmAdiVaHK4dhL F9dcB5SiD7cSD2jrxdZruldnmAdiVaHK4dhLv0
a=ssrc:1640957078 mslabel:F9dcB5SiD7cSD2jrxdZruldnmAdiVaHK4dhL
a=ssrc:1640957078 label:F9dcB5SiD7cSD2jrxdZruldnmAdiVaHK4dhLv0



type: answer, sdp: v=0
o=- 2519254656827397438 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS EHj5nMGJ5YJNdu7FKGq4wVhXXJZ9pzj8tiD4
m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 107 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:gjKGSQjT7UCKli97
a=ice-pwd:/7sbePOVufFaO/jyETlTon1s
a=fingerprint:sha-256 E0:D8:C0:CF:B8:59:D3:CA:76:1E:6A:0C:9B:58:78:41:EC:BD:F2:6A:13:D6:B9:CC:82:9A:FB:16:AA:FB:76:75
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:107 CN/48000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:3561414579 cname:oYDNJglSfZdK4lbv
a=ssrc:3561414579 msid:EHj5nMGJ5YJNdu7FKGq4wVhXXJZ9pzj8tiD4 EHj5nMGJ5YJNdu7FKGq4wVhXXJZ9pzj8tiD4a0
a=ssrc:3561414579 mslabel:EHj5nMGJ5YJNdu7FKGq4wVhXXJZ9pzj8tiD4
a=ssrc:3561414579 label:EHj5nMGJ5YJNdu7FKGq4wVhXXJZ9pzj8tiD4a0
m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:gjKGSQjT7UCKli97
a=ice-pwd:/7sbePOVufFaO/jyETlTon1s
a=fingerprint:sha-256 E0:D8:C0:CF:B8:59:D3:CA:76:1E:6A:0C:9B:58:78:41:EC:BD:F2:6A:13:D6:B9:CC:82:9A:FB:16:AA:FB:76:75
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc:201046042 cname:oYDNJglSfZdK4lbv
a=ssrc:201046042 msid:EHj5nMGJ5YJNdu7FKGq4wVhXXJZ9pzj8tiD4 EHj5nMGJ5YJNdu7FKGq4wVhXXJZ9pzj8tiD4v0
a=ssrc:201046042 mslabel:EHj5nMGJ5YJNdu7FKGq4wVhXXJZ9pzj8tiD4
a=ssrc:201046042 label:EHj5nMGJ5YJNdu7FKGq4wVhXXJZ9pzj8tiD4v0
```

Comment: inplace of a=sendrecv i get a=recvonly , how do change these now

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your TURN server is misconfigured (or the credentials are wrong); you should take a look at the `chrome://webrtc-internals` page and verify that there is an ICE candidate with the IP for your TURN server. The offer and answer that you posted don't contain any ICE candidates, since Chrome uses [trickle ICE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ivov-mmusic-trickle-ice-01).

You may want to try other applications with the same network configuration such as [AppRTC](https://apprtc.appspot.com) or [vLine link](https://vline.com) to see if you are able to connect with them.